# Angular CDK - Injecting the Custom overlay container class into a component creates new instance of it

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

**Requirement**

Use a custom `OverlayContainer` class in order to open Angular Material `Snackbars` on a specific DOM element (not on `body`).

At this point, I know that:

- the `OverlayContainer` class is a singleton
- I want to display **only the snackbars on a specific DOM element** and let the Dialogs, Tooltips and the other Material elements use the default overlay container element that is appended to `body`.

**The code I've tried**

I provided the custom class in the providers array.

```js
providers: [
  {provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: AppOverlayContainer}
]
```

And the class is:

```js
export class AppOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {

  /**
   * Append the OverlayContainer to the custom element
   */
   public appendToCustomContainer(element: HTMLElement): void {


     // this._containerElement is 'cdk-overlay-container'
     element.appendChild(this._containerElement);
   }

   **
   * Remove the OverlayContainer from the custom element and append it to body
   */
   public removeFromCustomContainer(): void {
     this._document.body.appendChild(this._containerElement);
   }
}
```

**In my component**, before opening a snackbar, I will call:

```js
AppOverlayContainer.appendToCustomContainer(HTMLElement)
```

And after the snackbar closes, I will call:

```js
AppOverlayContainer.removeFromCustomContainer();
```

**The issue:**

When injecting the `AppOverlayContainer` into the component constructor, it will create a new instance of this class and also of the `OverlayContainer`:

```js
constructor(
  private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private _appOverlayContainer: AppOverlayContainer
) {}
```

It works only if I inject the `OverlayContainer`, then use it like:

```js
constructor(
  private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private _appOverlayContainer: OverlayContainer
) {}
```

```js
(this._appOverlayContainer as AppOverlayContainer).appendToCustomContainer(appOverlayWrapperContainer);

(this._appOverlayContainer as AppOverlayContainer).removeFromCustomContainer();
```

Which seems kind of tricky.

I really don't understand what I am missing here.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wksbmf-9xdxcv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `useExisting` to avoid this problem having two instances of your services. The reason is some components are asking for `OverlayContainer` and some are asking for `AppOverlayContainer` and angular created instances for each. Updating the `useClass` to `useExisting` will help to let angular only use one instance:

```
providers: [
  {provide: OverlayContainer, useExisting: AppOverlayContainer}
]
```

You can check [here](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/08/17/using-useclass-usefactory-usevalue-useexisting-with-treeshakable-providers-in-angular/) for the details, it will be helpful to understand different properties while using services.